# query a sub-collection of a collection with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a collection of products, and each product object has it's own ProductImages collection.  Each ProductImage object has a IsMainImage bool field.  I'm having a hard time building a Linq query like this:

```
select products.productimages.imagename where products.productid == 1 and     
product.productimages.ismainimage == true
```

Can anyone help me figure this out, point me to an online resource where I can learn about writing linq queries like this, or both?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try something like

```
from product in products
where product.productid == 1
from image in product.productimages
where image.ismainimage
select image.imagename
```

I also found this list of [101 linq queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx) which may contain good information for you.

Comment: I usually look at that page -- what is the name of the example on there that I can find this under?  thanks so much, will accept when I'm allowed :)

Answer (score 7):

You can also use .SelectMany() projection method also.

```
        products.Where(product => product.productid == 1)
                .SelectMany(product => 
                                        product.productimages.Where(image => image.ismainimage)
                                                             .Select(image => image.imagename)
                           );
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to write the query is to select first image that is the main image for the product 1:

```
var q = from p in products 
        where p.ProductID == 1 
        select p.ProductImages.First(img => img.IsMainImage);
```

I would think this is more readable than nested `from` clauses (which are usually used for joins and similar constructs). Using `First` may be also more efficient, but that's just a guess (and it very likely doesn't matter)